# Instance variable vs local variable in the Create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As far as I understand we use namely an instance variable in the method `new`

```
def new
  @article = Article.new
end
```

because this variable is used in `new.html.erb` too. (Please correct me if I am wrong).

But why do we use an instance variable in the `create` method? Where else is it used outside the `create` method? Can't we just use a local variable `article` instead of the instance variable `@article`?

```
def create
  article = Article.new(article_params)

  if article.save
    flash[:success] = "Article created successfully!"
    redirect_to  articles_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end 
end

private  
def article_params
   params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because `@article` variable is also used in `new.html.erb` file, rendered when `article` isn't saved successfully.

So you'll get (as far as I remember) error `undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It is used by `new`. I've just figured out it, when my rspec-test failed and so it rendered the `new`. Since I used a local version of `article` it ended up with an error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This means that you don't understand `render :new`.

This line means that the view for the `new` method will be rendered, but the method itself will NOT be invoked. That's why you need the variable to be instance variable, because if the validations fails, you will need it to pass it to form.

Take a look at the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) for more information

PS `render :new` is the same as `render 'new'`